# In memory spatial index for frequent updating point objects

Tags: spatial-index

Is there any in memory spatial index specialized for frequent updating point objects?

The dataset will be moving cars, most likely update per second but with millions of them.

The project will be written in c/c++.

Comment: In what software?  Please **edit** this question to contain *several paragraphs* describing your platform, GIS software, and data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Try TPR-tree from [libspatialindex](https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex). It features:

- Generic main memory and disk based storage managers.
- TPR-tree index.